# Count number of sporadic events matched to reoccuring events [excel]

Tags: excel, countif

I have two tables of different length:

1. a table of monthly data (e.g.: value of inventory at start of month)
2. a table of sporadic events which happened at random point throughout the year (e.g.: truck delivery to storage)

In table one, I would like to count in an extra column, the number of events from table 2 that occurred in that month. The table with the value of the inventory would show a count per row of how many trucks were unloaded.

I've been fighting with countifs but I just cannot get it to work due to different table lengths, the weird way to enter criteria etc.

I've tried to match the month and year of a truck delivery with the period in the inventory table.

```
=COUNTIFS(
<range: Dates of Truck deliveries from Table2>, "=MONTH(" &
<cellOfInventoryDate> & ")", 
<range: Dates of Truck deliveries from Table2>, "=Year(" & 
<cellOfInventoryDate> & ")")
```

I have a feeling there is a simple solution to this an dI just hit a wall.

Thanks

Table

```
 1 - Inventory at start of month
01/01/2015  1000
01/02/2015  1200
01/03/2015  1100
01/04/2015   900
...



Table 2 - Date of Truck Delivery
01/01/2015
04/02/2015
07/02/2015
03/04/2015
11/07/2015
```

Comment: Please provide example input and desired output.

Comment: You need to at least attempt to solve this yourself.  Please share what you have so far.  See also [mcve] and [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here the answer.

I created a helper column in Table 2 which normalises the dates to the first of the month

```
=EOMONTH(cellwithdate,-1)+1
```

then I used countif (not countifs) to count when the date of the inventory matches the helper column.

```
=COUNTIF(helpercolumn, dateOfInventory)
```

this then counts how many deliveries were made in the month of that inventory's month.